# Function works well alone, but not assigned to a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, lambda, tkinter

I´m a begginer with python, and I hope that somebody can help me with this, I´m in a stack. I´m writing a simple code that conects with an odometer by ITCIP, recive data, process it and store in a dictionary, when some defined distance is reached the while loop breaks and return a dictionary with the data. These function works perfect alone.

The problem comes when I want to execute the function from a GUI with Tkinter, I assign the function to a button, when the button is pressed the function starts, but is blocked in the last loop, if I close the GUI the function show the data in the console, but doesn´t return the dictinary, any error appears. I try with "lambda:", without it, executing an external script with "execfile()", calling the function in a external file, and the functions never ends. Only when ist breaked with Crt+c. Here is a reduced code of "odom.py":

```
from Tkinter import *  
import socket  
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
v0=Tk()
v0.config(bg="gray")
v0.geometry("400x300")
v0.title("GUI")

def func():
    ITCIPadress='172.17.18.21'
    port=6000

    i=0 #initialize the dictionary
    rueda = {i:{
        'position':i,
        'distance':i}}

    distancetomeasure=float(raw_input("distance to measure(in m): "))
    dist=float(0)
    distincr=float(0)
    rev=0.5 ##odometer wheel circunference in meter
    stepsrev=8192.0#Number of steps/revolution in the odometer

    s = socket.socket()   
    s.connect((ITCIPadress, port))

    while dist<=distancetomeasure: #It works in positive and negative direction
        recibido = s.recv(45)#number of bytes recived
        print "Recibido:", recibido
        Postime_tmp=map(int, re.findall('\d+', recibido))#split the data
        position_tmp=int(Postime_tmp[0])

        rueda.update({i:{'position':Postime_tmp[0],
                          'distance':dist}})

        if i>0: #because when i=0 there is no increment
            incr_tmp=(rueda[i]['position']-rueda[i-1]['position'])
            distincr=(incr_tmp/stepsrev)*rev
            print distincr
            dist=dist+distincr        
            print 'the distance till yet is:', dist

        rueda.update({i:{'position':Postime_tmp[0],
                      'distance':dist}})
        i=i+1
    print "the distance from start point is:", dist
    s.close()            
    return rueda

b1=Button(v0,text='Start the odometer',command= lambda: func())
b1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)          #command= execfile(C:\odometer.py)[calling another file with the function]
v0.mainloop()                         #command= lambda: odometer.measuredistance()[calling another file with the function]

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    rueda = func()
```

If I comment the part of the GUI, and unblock the last two lines, it works perfectly, but within a GUI doesn´t. I cannot understand why this behavior happens.

This is with the GUI, measuring 1 meter, it stacks on the last:

```
0.037109375
the distance till yet is: 0.896179199219
Recibido: POSITION=25403046 TIMESTAMP=104308321 

0.0422973632812
the distance till yet is: 0.9384765625
Recibido: POSITION=25403756 TIMESTAMP=104502033 

0.0433349609375
the distance till yet is: 0.981811523438
Recibido:
```

and this is executing only the function, measuring 1 meter too:

```
0.037109375
the distance till yet is: 0.896179199219
Recibido: POSITION=25403046 TIMESTAMP=104308321 

0.0422973632812
the distance till yet is: 0.9384765625
Recibido: POSITION=25403756 TIMESTAMP=104502033 

0.0433349609375
the distance till yet is: 0.981811523438
Recibido: POSITION=25404477 TIMESTAMP=104705956 

0.0440063476562
the distance till yet is: 1.02581787109
the distance from start point is: 1.02581787109
```

this last one returns also the dictionary with all the interest values. Any help will be grateful! Thanks

Comment: `command=func`; there's no need to wrap a call in a `lambda` expression, as `func` is *already* a reference to a zero-argument function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not use a `raw_input` inside a function called by a `GUI`. Instead, try to build your `GUI`, with an input field for your 'distancetomeasure' variable.

After that, instead of returning the results, why not building another widget `GUI` to display these ?

It's been a long time since I last used `Tkinter`, but it's a nice `GUI`, and you should, if you have the time, how to build a nice app by visiting http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm for example.

But if you're in a hurry, I'm sure other fellows here will gladly help you :)

Comment: Feel free to accept one answer if you're satistfied with it :)

Comment: At the end I build it with the threading method, and it works well, the problem now is how to print the info in a text box or in a label. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html Here's an example. At the bottom, there's the python code. Notice the 'feet = StringVar()', 'meters = StringVar()' and how the calculate function use the get() and set() methods on these. Then, you just need to use these StringVar on you label or text definition, with textvariable=my_string_var. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

the reason you are not seeing anything returned is that it effectively gets returned to the button you are using to call the function, as @Yann says, you should try and build up your GUI to do the entire of your program, otherwise there is little point to having both a GUI and command line visible to the user